# Does the proceeding of logics necessarily agree with the order of operation?

Tags: logic

In mathematical logic, from the boolean algebra, it could ensure that the proceeding of logics necessarily agree with the order of operation.
For example, say a logic operation $O_1(A)\equiv( A \wedge \bot)$, then with a given boolean value $b(A)=T$, $O_1(A)=F$. Then there could be $O_2(),O_3()...$ and $O_n(...,O_1(A))$.

However, for some cases, it brought up a question weather the proceeding of logics always agree with the order of operation. i.e. what if a or several non constant parameters were to be inserted into the logic operations or even the boolean algebra, i.e. $O_1(A,t_1)$ and $b(A,t_2)$, such that $O_n(...,O_1(A))$ were no longer determined started from $O_1(A)$, but rather changing with the successive application of the operator $O_n()$? i.e. at $O_x()$ the $t_1$ value were changed thus $O_1(A,t_1)$ were not necessarily in agreement with the $O_1(A,t_1)$ at $O_{x+1}()$? and in fact $O_n(...,O_1(A))$ were seemingly to have many different results?

Could such construction of logic be sensible? Does the proceeding of logics necessarily agree with the order of operation?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the proceeding of logics"? The order in which expressions are evaluated?

Comment: I don't understand the term 'proceeding of logics' also.

Comment: @lemontree For example, say if you were given $b(A)=T$, then you apply a logic operation $O_1(A)= A\wedge \bot$, what's the boolean value of $O_1$? Then apply $O_2,O_3$ etc. and by successive operation, what's the boolean value at the end? i.e. the logic results "proceeding" from the given results in each step.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood basically, in previous cases, when given $b(O_1(A))=T$ and operate $O_n(...)$, look back one could be sure that $b(O_1(A))=T$. But what if when given $b(O_1(A))=T$ and operate $O_n(...)$, look back one found out that $b(O_1(A))\neq T$ but rather $b(O_1(A))=F$? i.e. one could be given a start, i.e. $b(O_1(A))=T$, but the logical determination could not necessarily be carried out in the order of operation unchanged, i.e. maybe $b(O_1(A))\neq T$.

Comment: So you mean that the semanitcs of a logic is, in a way, non-linear, in that the truth value of a subexpression may change during the process of evaluating other operators?

Comment: @lemontree somewhat yes, the boolean operation itself might change as well, i.e. $b(A)=T$ could became $b(A)=F$, but this might be achieved by replacing every letter to an operation on letters i.e. $B(A)\equiv b(N_1(A,t_1))$, etc.